# batch command line that duplicate any folder inside a parent folder and copy it to original folder

Tags: windows, command-line, batch

Example: I running window 10 and I have a parent folder that contain 3 folder: A, B, C

X/A

X/B

X/C

I want to duplicate 3 of them and copy each of that copy folder into the original folder.

Ex: 
X/A/A-copy

X/B/B-copy

X/C/C-copy

So can anyone help me to write a command line for a batch file so it can duplicate and copy any folder inside the parent folder ?

Also I want to rename all copy folder and its file, i want to remove all the words character that they contain and left only the number character.

Can someone help me solve this ? Thanks you guys so much.

Sorry for my bad explanation and terrible english grammar :)

Answer (score 0):

```sh
@echo off
for /d %%d in (*) do (
    md %%d-copy
    copy %%d\*.* %%d-copy\*.* > nul
    move %%d-copy %%d\%%d-copy > nul
    )
echo Done.
```

The script do NOT check if destination folder exists (both in parent folder and in particular folder). You may add this check if you need...